# Where does the command output get written in laravel?

Tags: laravel, command, laravel-5.1

I want to know where the output of laravel scheduled command is written when it gets executed

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('inspire')
             ->hourly();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default its written nowhere. Laravel sugested Cronjob redirect the console [output to `/dev/null`](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/06/06/what-does-devnull-21-mean/).

```
* * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

But you can redirect the console output to a file or send it through email:

```
$schedule->command('foo')
         ->daily()
         ->sendOutputTo($filePath)
         ->emailOutputTo('foo@example.com');
```

You can found more information on [Laravel's documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/scheduling#task-output).